# Prove product of sequence less than other for all n using induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, products, pi

Given two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$, with the former always smaller than the latter, I want to prove that $\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i \le \prod_{i=1}^{n}b_i$.

I know I'm going to use induction on n, and have verified the base case, with n=0. However, I am having trouble with how to proceed. How can I get started with showing $\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}a_i \le \prod_{i=1}^{k+1}b_i$ from $\prod_{i=1}^{k}a_i \le \prod_{i=1}^{k}b_i$?

Comment: $(-7)(-6)\not \leq (-2)(-1)$ despite $-7\leq -2$ and $-6\leq -1$.  You need the additional condition that all terms are non-negative.  Note that for $x,y,z$ with $x$ non-negative one has $y<z\implies xy<xz$.  Using this property twice in succession one learns that $0\leq a\leq b$ and $0\leq c\leq d$ implies $ac\leq bd$.

Comment: The proof for your problem follows *directly* from this observation and induction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ${a_n}, {b_n}$ are non-negative, we have.

$\prod_{i=1}^{k}a_i \le \prod_{i=1}^{k}b_i \implies \prod_{i=1}^{k+1}a_{i} = \prod_{i=1}^{k}a_{i} * a_{k+1} \le \prod_{i=1}^{k}a_i * b_{k+1} \le \prod_{i=1}^{k}b_i * b_{k+1} = \prod_{i=1}^{k+1}b_i$

Comment: Except that if $a_n$ and $b_n$ must additionally be assumed non-negative for the above to happen, as was pointed  out in a comment above.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction.